# Quotes in vuejs templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My component template vue.js file reports me some quote errors:
[image]

The line with this code: :state="validateState('form.name')"

And the line with this code: :state="validateState('form.foods')"

How fix this for a Vue.js template?, this solution: :state="validateState("form.name")" not works for me

Comment: This might work: `\'form.name\'` or use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: To concatenate a variable with a string, use the `+` operator. `validateState('+form.name+')`. You also might have to add additional quotes there, if you want to treat it as a string argument to that function.

Comment: Depending on your target browser(s), you could use backtick template literals and avoid the quote escaping – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 3):

The issue is from you using single quotes to declare your template.

```
template: '...'
```

I would suggest using the template literals and you don't need to include backslashes for end lines and such.

```
template: `...`
```

The other option you have is escaping the following single quote

```
template: '\'somestring\''
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using single quotes anywhere, you cant use single quotes again inside there.

use template literals or care about single-double quotes.